# Asm Beginner help

Tags: assembly

hey i`d like to know more about asm, im totally new and i dont know anything about it yet and i would be very happy if someone could like explain it to me or show me a good video.

thanks.

Comment: Search the assembly tag, there's lots of good info on this site.

Comment: How about a book? http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/aoa.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any general programming experience?  If you are a beginner to programming, I wouldn't suggest you start with something like Assembly.

If you provide a bit of background regarding your experience we can suggest something more appropriate if you are wanting to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Download masm32 assembler and take a look at the examples (for Windows). It's a good start...

For Linux try http://asm.sourceforge.net/

Anyway, also here is a good start: http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~kslarsen/dm18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try the

> Art of Assembly Language
>   : http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/aoa.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If You got visual studio (no express version... it does not support assembler) You can write little asm inline programs.